# Facebook like button disappears when going to a previous page and then returning to the original page

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

I am using a Facebook like button in my webpage and it appears on my website, but  after clicking to the previous page and returning to the original page it disappears. To prevent it, I should go to the previous page, reload it and click the exact page where the like button appears.

Here is my like button code. I fixed it by using `$window.reload` in angular, but I am looking for another solution (if one exists).

Please help.

```
              #fb-root
              script.
                (function (d, s, id) {
                  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s);
                  js.id = id;
                  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2';
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

              .fb-like( data-layout='box_count',  data-action='like', data-show-faces='true', data-share='false')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS SDK goes through your document once on initialization and looks for elements to replace with social plugins.

In a system where you switch out content dynamically via AJAX, you need to call the method the SDK provides to re-iterate the current state of the document:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/